# How to put extremely long text that spread over several pages in a table cell

Tags: tables

To conform to the form of a company Word template, I have to put a very long text in a table cell.  But I can not find a way not to overflow the bottom of a page.  Is there a way in LaTeX that enables the long text in a table cell to spread over several pages?  I have tried several tabular packages but none of them produces the required result.  Even the `xtab` package does not do the job.  Essentially I want the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
\hline
Lorem Ipsum & \lipsum[1-9]  \\
\hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

to produce something similar to what you will get when put the long text in a table cell in a word processor like MS Word or LibreOffice Writer.  The long text continues in a continued table in the next page.

Comment: do not use a table setting for that, use a list `\item[Lorem Ipsum] \lipsum[1-9]`  almost every table with a column spec of `lp{..}` is better set as a list.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a list here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\begin{description}[leftmargin=9em,labelwidth=9em,labelsep=0pt]

\item[Lorem Ips]\lipsum[1]  
\item[Lorem Ipsum] \lipsum[1-9]  

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, David.  I do want to use list for that purpose.  Problem is that the company MS Word template uses table, and we are required to conform to that strictly.